# Multi Column to One Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing a trigger and I am using inserted 
Inserted is a single row 
like

```
ColumnX |ColumnY|ColumnZ|
=========================
 A      | B     |C      |
```

I want to insert results to another table like this

```
ColumnName |Value|
==================
ColumnX    | A   |
ColumnY    | B   |
ColumnZ    | C   |
```

I have a lot of tables how can I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNPIVOT` the result set, then insert them:

```
INSERT INTO Anothertable(Columnname, value)
SELECT Columnname, value
FROM tablename t
UNPIVOT
(
   value
   FOR ColumnName IN(ColumnX, ColumnY, ColumnZ)
) AS u;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14f794/1)

---

To do this dymaincally:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Columnname)
                      FROM table1 t
UNPIVOT
(
   value
   FOR ColumnName IN(ColumnX, ColumnY, ColumnZ)
) AS u
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT Columnname, value
              FROM table1 t
              UNPIVOT
              (
                 value
                 FOR ColumnName IN( ' + @cols + ' )
              ) AS u;'

execute(@query);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14f794/4)

Comment: Is there any way make it unless write ColumnNames because I will use it all tables and tables have a lot of columns

Comment: @user1624185 - OK I will update my answer with the dynamic version .

Comment: @user1624185 - See my edit, but put the `INSERT INTO ...` before the select dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON YourDatabase.TableName
AFTER INSERT 
AS
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO OtherTable (ColumnX, ColumnY, ColumnZ) 
        SELECT ColumnX, ColumnY, ColumnZ
        FROM inserted
  END
GO
```